# Remember icon size, sort order, and sort options per-folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, icons, sorting

Sometimes when I change the icon size in one folder, all other folders are changed, too.  Sometimes they are unchanged:

[image]

Sometimes when I change the sort order, all other folders change too, sometimes they are unchanged:

[image]

Usually, when I add sort options, they are later forgotten:

[image]

How can I get Windows 7 to remember all of these things on a per-folder basis, so that whenever I open a folder, it is sorted in the same way as last time, with the same icon size as last time?  Installing 3rd-party add-ons like Listary is fine, as long as I don't have to change the sort type and icon view every time I switch from one folder to another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set Windows Explorer to remember individual folder view settings for folders included in libraries. 
All libraries and its included folders share the same view.

The feature was available in the other windows versions and has been left out, probably for performance issues.